# File size limit in child only for files created by parent?

Tags: linux, file, process, limit, ulimit

How to restrict size of files created by parent but no limit for file generated by child?

I have a use case where parent process redirect STDOUT to a file and child process writes to STDOUT (which will be redirected to the file created by parent process).

I have set filesize limit on parent process of 50 MB and there is no limit for child process.

How can I make sure that parent process get SIGXFSZ when file size for file where STDOUT is redirected is more than 50 MB.

Answer (score 1):

File size is limited and `SIGXFSZ` is generated when `RLIMIT_FSIZE` limit is set using [`setrlimit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html).

Child process inherits resource limits from parent:

> A child process created via `fork(2)` inherits its parent's resource
>          limits.  Resource limits are preserved across `execve(2)`.

Resource limits are *per-process* attributes, not global and not per-file. Specifically, for `RLIMIT_FSIZE`:

> **`RLIMIT_FSIZE`**
>
> The maximum size of files that the **process** may create.
>                 Attempts to extend a file beyond this limit result in delivery
>                 of a `SIGXFSZ` signal.  `[...]`

This limit is applied when a process changes file size. If file size becomes greater than `RLIMIT_FSIZE` value of **current** process, `SIGXFSZ` and `EFBIG` are generated.

---

You can check this in kernel sources. See [`mm/filemap.c`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/filemap.c#L2289):

```c
inline ssize_t generic_write_checks(struct kiocb *iocb, struct iov_iter *from)
{
     ...

     unsigned long limit = rlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE);

     ...

     if (limit != RLIM_INFINITY) {
             if (iocb->ki_pos >= limit) {
                     send_sig(SIGXFSZ, current, 0);
                     return -EFBIG;
             }

             ...
```

and [`include/linux/sched.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L3150):

```c
static inline unsigned long rlimit(unsigned int limit)
{
      return task_rlimit(current, limit);
}
```

Note that [`current`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/current.h) here is a pointer to current *process*.

---

To sum up:

- if parent sets `RLIMIT_FSIZE`, this limit is applied when *parent* writes to *any* file;
- if child overwrites `RLIMIT_FSIZE`, the new limit is applied when *child* writes to *any* file.

> Parent process has some limit and if any file created by parent exceed limit it should get `SIGXFSZ`. Now child is merely writting data to file created by parent so shouldn't size of file be considered in parents limit?

No, it shouldn't. When child is writing to file, kernel checks child's value of `RLIMIT_FSIZE`. Kernel doesn't bother which process created or opened the file.

Comment: Currently I am setting setrlimit for parent and then invoking a shell command with either (ulimit -S -f unlimited; or limit filesize unlimited) option depending on shell. But problem I am trying to solve is that if stdout file as described in question exceeds filesize limit then it should raise signal.

Comment: @learner, So you want to get `SIGXFSZ` in child, but only for files created in parent (i.e. kind of per-file limit)?

Comment: Not exactly. Parent process has some limit and if any file created by parent exceed limit it should get SIGXFSZ. Now child is merely writting data to file created by parent so shouldn't size of file be considered in parents limit?

Comment: @learner, I also suggest to rename the question to avoid misunderstanding. It should be clear that you want different limits for different files in child. Maybe something like "File size limit in child only for files created by parent?"